# Constant in Maximal sobolev regularity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, regularity

We know the following evolution equation
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{llc}
 v_t=A v+f,\\
v(0)=0.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
$A$ generates a bounded analytic semigroup on a Banach Space. We say $A$ has maximal $L^p$-regularity if all $f\in L^p([0,T),X)$, $v_t$ and $Av$ belong to $L^p([0,T),X)$, and there exists $C_p>0$ such that 
$$\|v_t\|_{L^p([0,T),X)}+\|Av\|_{L^p([0,T),X)}\le C_p \|f\|_{L^p([0,T),X)}.$$
My question is how $C_p$ depends on $p$. Could anyone give an upper estimate of $C_p$?

In fact, for the heat semigroup on the whole space, $C_p\le c_1 p^\tau$ with $c_1,\tau>0$ known constants. I anticipate the same for a general operator, at least for the Neumann heat semigroup on a bounded domain.

Comment: Dear @user45350, please check that my edit did not change the intended meaning of the question. Specifically, I changed a problematic period (in the definition of maximal $L^p$-regularity) to a comma, which may have changed the intended meaning.

Comment: Sorry that I revive this thread, but do you have a reference for this assertion with the heat semigroup?